# Traefik TCP service + routing

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, routes, traefik

I'm having a hard time routing TCP traffic to a Pod with Traefik.
This pod I'm trying to proxy is named "realtime" and namespaced under "default"

According to the doc provided by traefik, I have created the following

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: realtime-tcp-route
  namespace: default
spec:
  routes:
    - match: HostSNI(`subdomain.hostname.com`)
      services:
        - name: realtime
          port: 3002
```

According to the traefik dashboard, something is wrong: **the service "default-realtime-tcp-ingress-542127811efa012038fd@kubernetescrd" does not exist**, what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

[image]